# PgBouncer keep so much connections with auth_user

Tags: postgresql, pgbouncer

I am using PgBouncer with Postgresql.
Besides connections from users. PgBouncer still keeps so much connections from auth_user.
These connections have no other information than query infomation: *Insufficient privilege*
These connections account for nearly 40% of total connections of DB.
Can I want reduce these connections to make slot for application connections?
My PgBouncer config:

```
[databases]
* = host=localhost port=1234 auth_user=pgbouncer

[pgbouncer]
listen_port = 1234
listen_addr = *
auth_type = md5
auth_file = ...
auth_query = ...
pidfile = pgbouncer.log
logfile = pgbouncer.pid
admin_users = pgbouncer
stats_users = pgbouncer
default_pool_size = 30
max_client_conn = 2000
max_db_connections = 0
min_pool_size = 0
pool_mode = transaction
reserve_pool_size = 0
reserve_pool_timeout = 5
query_timeout = 0
ignore_startup_parameters = extra_float_digits
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[databases]
* = host=localhost port=1234 auth_user=pgbouncer

[pgbouncer]
listen_port = 1234
```

It is hard to see how making pgbouncer loop back to itself could do anything useful.  Was this just the product if misbegotten anonymization?

Anyway, it will maintain one auth_user connection for every database. You should set auth_dbname to funnel all those connections to one database, where they can be shared.

> These connections have no other information than query infomation: Insufficient privilege

As said in a previous iteration, monitoring is more effective if you use a user  which has sufficient privileges to monitor.